# how to use blit=true for animation subplot in python tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, animation, tkinter

The following code is a simplified version of my project, and it could run and plot with animation, but I have to add `blit=true` in the animation to speed up (my original UI is much more complicated and slow). I know the animation function must return a sequence of Artist objects. here what is the artist object in my `subplot_2`? I tried `subplot_2,a,f`, none of them work. Many thanks

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
##, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib import style
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
f = Figure(figsize=(6,6), dpi=100)
subplot_1 = f.add_subplot(211)
subplot_2 = f.add_subplot(212)

LARGE_FONT= ("Verdana", 12)
style.use("ggplot")

def animate(i):
    time = np.random.rand(2, 25)  
    data = np.random.rand(2, 25)   
    a = subplot_2.scatter(time,data,c='blue',s=2)
    #return a

class home(tk.Tk):

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):        
    tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "Graph ")       
    self.geometry("1000x1000")

    container = tk.Frame(self)
    container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)
    container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

    self.frames = {}
    F=Graph
    frame=Graph(container, self)
    self.frames[F] = frame
    frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
    self.show_frame(Graph)

def show_frame(self, cont):
    frame = self.frames[cont]
    frame.tkraise()
def get_frame(self, frame_class):
    return self.frames[frame_class]
##     
class Graph(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        global canvas
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text=" ", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=120,padx=10)
        collectbtn=Button(self,text='collect',command=self.clickstart)
        collectbtn.place(x=200,y=100)
        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, self)
##        canvas.draw()
        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
        canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
    def clickstart(self):
        animate(0)
        #aniplot_photon = animation.FuncAnimation(f, animate, blit=True,interval=100)
        aniplot_photon = animation.FuncAnimation(f, animate, interval=100)
        canvas.draw()
app = home()
app.mainloop()
```

**Updates:**
 Thanks to the William's answer, it works. However, I have further questions, if this subplot include many curves `"subplot_2.scatter(x1..),subplot_2.scatter(x2..),subplot_2.scatter(x3..),subplot_2.scatter(x1..)..."`, or some subplots are updated from different threads (make objects and global them?), it will be hard to put all curves into return list. However, I found a simple solution for the above listed problems, I could just use `return [subplot_2]` and it will update all plots inside subplot_2, but the coordinates(x ticks) are lost (run and you will see). is there a simple way I could keep the coordinates when I use `return [suplot_2]`?

```
    def animate(i):
    time = np.random.rand(2, 25)  
    data = np.random.rand(2, 25)   
    a = subplot_2.scatter(time,data,c='blue',s=2)
    return [subplot_2]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`matplotlib.pyplot.scatter`](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html) returns an artist (a `PathCollection` to be exact), so the artist you need to return from `animate` is stored in `a`. However, `FuncAnimation` requires a **sequence** of artists, so

```py
    return a
```

is insufficient (as this is a single artist, not a sequence). You can use one of

```py
    return [a]
```

or

```py
    return a,
```

to satisfy the "*sequence of artists*" requirement.

Comment: thanks, in this blit=true, the history plot is not stored, so I have to plot differently, try to store every time data into a long list, and every time plot the whole list again?

Comment: in my original project, it is easier to return [subplot_2] then return [a], so I do not need to specify every curve on subplot_2, however, in this way, I lost the coordination info on the figure, any ideas to keep those coordinates on subplot_2?

Comment: @adamwu In the example, `subplot_2` is scoped such that you can still access it outside the loop - so you can use [`matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_children()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_children.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_children) to access the individual `PathCollection`s created by `plt.scatter`.

Comment: you mean I use return [subplot_2], and then use axes.get to plot the coordinates again?  not very understand, a few line codes will be helpful^_^

Comment: @adamwu You don't need to return `subplot_2` in order to access the children artists, you can just do `artists = subplot_2.get_children()`, `artists` will then be a list of artists containing all the `PathCollection`s from `subplot_2.scatter` (among other things). At whatever point you need to access them after calling `FuncAnimation` you can use this approach.

Comment: I have to return [subplot_2] or return [a], as animation requires you to return something(the curves or scatters you want to update) to match "blit=True", which will make animation faster

Comment: @adamwu I must apologize, I'm not clear exactly what you're asking in your comments. You may want to consider either editing your current question or opening a new question.